# Click on all combinations from the dropdown menu and print the text result in Selenium + Python: wait function is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get all combinations from this site: https://www.kgm.gov.tr/Sayfalar/KGM/SiteTr/Otoyollar/OtoyolUcretSorgu.aspx

Sorry for the language of this site is Turkish. I will translate the texts, which require you to understand the problem. Translations of dropdown menu options:

Otoban = Highway

Girisi Gisesi = Beginning of highway

Cikis Gisesi = End of the highway

Arac sinifi = Vehicle grade

Ucreti Hesapla = Calculate the price, between the beginning and end of the highway

So basically I want to click on all options respectively and click on "Ucreti Hesapla" to see the price and save.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


url = "https://www.kgm.gov.tr/Sayfalar/KGM/SiteTr/Otoyollar/OtoyolUcretSorgu.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/atkarakas/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
highways = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl58_g_317e7991_4b2e_47d1_b939_7e3f3b7c8256_ctl00_ddlOtoyol"]'))
for highway in highways.options:
    highways.select_by_value(highway.get_attribute('value'))

    beginnings= Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl58_g_317e7991_4b2e_47d1_b939_7e3f3b7c8256_ctl00_ddlGise1"]'))
    for beginning in beginnings.options:
        beginnings.select_by_value(beginning.get_attribute('value'))

        ends = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl58_g_317e7991_4b2e_47d1_b939_7e3f3b7c8256_ctl00_ddlGise2"]'))
        for end in ends.options:
            ends.select_by_value(end.get_attribute('value'))

            vehicles = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl58_g_317e7991_4b2e_47d1_b939_7e3f3b7c8256_ctl00_ddlAracSinifi"]'))
            for vehicle in vehicles.options:
                vehicles.select_by_value(vehicle.get_attribute('value'))

                #The code works fine until here, the main problem begins here
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl58_g_317e7991_4b2e_47d1_b939_7e3f3b7c8256_ctl00_Sorgula"]').click()
                results=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl58_g_317e7991_4b2e_47d1_b939_7e3f3b7c8256_ctl00_LblResult"]').text
                print (results)
driver.close()
```

When I run the code this error is rising: `StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`.

I know I have to use `time.sleep()` or `WebDriverWait()`. I read this documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

I tried every "wait" function to solve the problem. But this is not works.

Which "wait" code should I use and where should I put it to save the text after `click()`? Or is there any other alternative method to see the results?

Comment: explain this for us please `So basically I want to click on all options respectively and click on "Ucreti Hesapla" to see the price and save. `

Comment: After i select the options, i want to see each text. After that, i want to save these text as dataframe (The text is at the below of the dropdown menu).